# как сюда добавить секундомер?

Tags: tkinter, время

```
from tkinter import *
from time import time
from random import *

clicks = 0


def randomize():
    global clicks
    btnClick.place(x=randint(70, 1000), y=randint(70, 650))
    clicks += 1
    labelClick['text'] = str(clicks)
    labelClick.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title('Clicker')
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root['bg'] = 'black'
labelClick = Label(root, text='0', font=('Comic Sans MS', 30, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='white')
labelClick.pack()

btnClick = Button(root,
                  text='Click on me',
                  bg='red',
                  fg='black',
                  padx='20',
                  pady='8',
                  font=('Comic Sans MS', 13, 'bold'),
                  command=randomize
                  )

btnClick.place(x=randint(70, 1000), y=randint(70, 650))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

ниже приложу тебе пример кода, который я доработал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Тут я добавил библиотеку datetime (from datetime import datetime)

И добавил несколько кнопок старт, стоп, рестарт и так далее

```
from datetime import datetime

temp = 0
after_id = ''

label1 = Label(root, width=10, font=('Comic Sans MS', 30), text="00:00") label1.pack() 

def tick():
global temp, after_id
after_id = root.after(1000, tick)
f_temp = datetime.fromtimestamp(temp).strftime("%M:%S")
label1.configure(text=str(f_temp))
temp += 1

def start_tick():
btnStart.pack_forget()
btnStop.pack()
tick()

def stop_tick():
btnStop.pack_forget()
btnContinue.pack()
btnReset.pack()
root.after_cancel()

btnStart = Button(root, text="Старт", font=('Comic Sans MS', 20), width=15, command=start_tick)

btnStop = Button(root, text="Стоп", font=('Comic Sans MS', 20), width=15, command=stop_tick)

btnContinue = Button(root, text="Продолжить", font=('Comic Sans MS', 20), width=15)

btnReset = Button(root, text="Сброс", font=('Comic Sans MS', 20), width=15)

btnStart.pack()
```

Попробуйте пожалуйста доработать кнопки рестарт и продолжение сами.